# using mysql sum function with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to figure out how to get correct results from a MySQL query which includes sum functions when the output is encoded as json.

The results return correctly when there are no sum functions (this might also be a problem for me with group by functions but I haven't tried that yet) but when there is a sum function in the MySQL query it only returns one result/object (which I'm assuming is the aggregate of the sum).

This is the first time I've used mysql_fetch_array() to retrieve array results and all the examples of how to implement json_encode on the web that I have found use this function. Is mysql_fetch_array() able to be used with sum and GROUP BY functions?

```
{


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT portfolio,agency,program,objectives_text,last,current FROM     `table`  WHERE MATCH(program,objectives_text) AGAINST('health'IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ");

    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
   $results[] = array(

      'portfolio' => $row['portfolio'],
      'agency' => $row['agency'],
      'program' => $row['program'],
        'objectives_text' => $row['objectives_text'],
      'component' => $row['component'],
      'last' => $row['last'],
      'current' => $row['current']
   );
}
$json = json_encode($results);

  echo
"$json";  

}

//the above code produces correct results in json output with integer value for each row correct

    {


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT portfolio,agency,program,objectives_text,last,current,sum(last),sum(current) FROM `table`  WHERE MATCH(program,objectives_text) AGAINST('health'IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ");

    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
   $results[] = array(

      'portfolio' => $row['portfolio'],
      'agency' => $row['agency'],
      'program' => $row['program'],
        'objectives_text' => $row['objectives_text'],
      'component' => $row['component'],
      'last' => $row['sum(last)'],
      'current' => $row['sum(current)']
   );
    }
    $json = json_encode($results);

     echo
    "$json";  

    }
//produces one result/object in the json output with the integer results being a sum of the individual rows
```

Comment: Can you post the query and code you are using?

Comment: Please show your code. There must be some basic problem.

Comment: show your code please!

Comment: At what level do you want the sum totals to be at? i.e. portfolio, agency, program,o bjectives_text. You will need to use 'group by' to get totals at the various levels. [Tutorial: sql-group-by](http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-group-by/). fyi, it is worthwhile developing the query separately in an 'SQL development query gui tool. here is an example list: [Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm).

Comment: I think you're right - it seems to be working now I've added in the group by function. Thanks!!